# Getting the -exec option in find to work

Tags: find

I am trying to make `find` print out a list of directories that contain files other than jpg images, but I think my use of the `-exec` option is broken. My environment is Cygwin Bash.

```
$ find ! -iname "*.JPG$" -exec dirname

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

```
$ find ! -iname "*.JPG$" -exec dirname {}

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

```
$ find ! -iname "*.JPG$" -exec dirname;

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

```
$ find ! -iname "*.JPG$" -exec dirname ;

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

```
$ find ! -iname "*.JPG$" -exec dirname {};

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer using `xargs` instead of find's -exec option, less shell escaping, and it's even in find's man page examples.

Comment: @Xen2050 It also fails on some filenames unless you have GNU `find` (`-print0`).

Comment: @jordanm That's true, it's in `man find`'s example `find /tmp -name core -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f` , should handle newlines in filenames too. `find` & `xargs` are together in the `findutils` package in Debian & every linux I've ever seen. Cygwin's `findutils` comes with `xargs.exe` too, and on gnu.org a coreutils-faq mentions *"The hard work the Cygwin team has done to port GNU Project software to MS-Windows is greatly admired"* so it should be a gnu find too

Answer (score 8):

A `-exec` needs to be terminated with a `;` or a `+`. The `;` causes the command to execute once per found filename, whereas `+` causes the command to be executed once for all filenames.

Here is a working example:

```
find ! -iname "*.JPG" -exec dirname {} \;
```

Some notable differences from your attempts:

1. There must be a space between `{}` and `\;`
2. The `;` must be escaped, because it is a shell metacharacter.
3. As @muru pointed out in his answer, `-iname` takes a glob, not a regex

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
find -type f ! -iname "*.JPG" -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u
```

Notes;

- To complete the `-exec` command, a `{}` is needed to show where the filename should go *and* a semicolon is needed.  Because the shell would eat a plain semicolon, we have to escape it so that it is passed on to `find`.
- `-iname` matches globs, not regular expressions.  So, the final `$` in `"*.JPG$"` is probably not what you want.
- You said that you want a "list of directories that contain files other than jpgs."  Consequently, I added `-type f` so that we would be sure that we only look at directories that contain at least one file.
- The results are put through `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax:

```
-exec [command] ... {} ... ;
-exec [command] ... {} ... +
```

Since `;` is part of shell syntax, you need to escape it so that `find` sees it as an argument:

```
find .. -exec dirname {} \;
```

By the way, `-iname` doesn't use regular expressions - just use `*.jpg` without the `$`.

---

It strikes me now that with GNU find we don't need to use `dirname` at all. Instead:

```
find ... -printf "%h\n"
```